# Как разбить абзац текста построчно?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Имеется такой див во vue.js:

```
<div class="page-message__text">
      {{ this.stringMessage.split(/(?<=[!?.])/).join("\n") }}
    </div>
```

Пытаюсь вывести новое предложение на новую строку, но никакие ухищрения здесь не работают. Текст такой: "Ваша заявка успешно отправлена! В течение 5 минут мы Вам перезвоним"

Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: <br /> - перевод строки

Answer (score 0):

Тег `<br>` - HTML и `<BR />` - XHTML устанавливает перевод строки в том месте, где этот тег находится.

```html
<div>
    Ваша заявка успешно отправлена! <BR/>В течение 5 минут мы Вам перезвоним
</div>
```